# Composer search error "Not enough arguments (missing: "tokens")"

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I was trying to build a repository for composer on bitbucket. The repository name looks like this: 
`bitbucket.org/example/composer`.

I also have a vendor directory with php files. Here is my composer.json file in the bitbucket repository, master branch:

```
{
  "name": "example/composer",
  "description": "composer repository",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "example\\composer\\": "vendor/"
    }
  }
}
```

here is my composer.json on server

```
{
  "name" : "example/composer",
  "description" : "composer repository",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:example/composer.git"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4"
  }
}
```

When I do Composer install it creates directory vendor with autoload files, but when I type Composer Search I get this error:

[image: Error message screenshot]

Comment: you need to pass argument to composer search method. What you want to search?

Comment: @Rainmx93 oh i get the mistake thx!)